# 20.04 SSH stops working when updating Ciphers

Tags: sftp

I am trying to setup SFTP for an ancient version of Cisco UC (7.1!).  I need to update the ciphers and key exchange options to allow the Cisco box to connect.  When I add the ciphers and kexalgorithms line to the sshd_config file I get "Connection Refused" when trying to ssh to the server.

---

```
    # Ciphers and keying
    #RekeyLimit default none
    Ciphers 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
    KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

---

If I remark the lines out and reboot everything is fine again.

I was getting the error about securetty missing, but after adding the securetty file in the /etc directory I no longer get any errors in the  /var/log/auth.log

Answer (score 0):

it hated blowfish and the ssh server would not start until I removed the blowfish option.  used "service ssh status" to check status of service and "service ssh start/restart" to test.